# Absolutely positioned view is not visible when you click to input text on iOS

Tags: position

we have a position absolute view with input text when we click to write something the view is not visible in ios

i used react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view to aware the input but it make the view scrollable which i am not looking for.